# What are the differences between all -device configurations available for configure Qt5

Tags: raspberry-pi, qt5, raspberry-pi3

I follow this tutorial : https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS#Step_by_step in order to compile Qt5.7 for Raspberry pi3.

I have succeeded to compile and start examples but after further investigations I found others device configuration in this directory :

> ls -l qt5/qtbase/mkspecs/devices/

It contains :

> ... 
>   linux-rasp-pi2-g++ 
>   linux-rasp-pi-g++ 
>   linux-rpi3-g++ 
>   linux-rpi3-vc4-g++ 
>   ...

I'm not sure what is the best device option I have to set for the ./configure for Raspberry Pi3, someone can explain the differences between all these configurations?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Raspberry Pi 3, you should use `linux-rpi3-g++` or `linux-rpi3-vc4-g++`.

`linux-rpi3-vc4-g++` should be used if you want to enable hardware acceleration. `VC` stands for Video Core. You have more information about Video Core IV in the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi). I think it's worth it to try this configuration.

`linux-rasp-pi-g++` is the configuration for the first model and `linux-rasp-pi2-g++` for the Raspberry Pi 2.